# hide the program icon and its name when alt+tab on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10

I want to ask please if there any way to hide the program icon and its name when alt+tab on Windows 10.
see the screenshot please:

[image: screenshot]

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: What is it you want to have happen?  Since Alt Tab is for fast task switching, without those how would you know what your switching to ?

Answer (score 0):

This is possible, but some registry keys need to be changed. If you can accept this method, you can refer to the detailed steps in the [link](https://www.tenforums.com/general-support/118502-hide-program-icon-its-name-when-alt-tab.html).